# How do I perform group, sort and limit aggregations together in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

my collection is something like this:

```
"_id": ObjectId(""),
"score": 500,
"year": 2015,
"batch": 1
"location": "Shenzhen"
```

what I am doing is this:

1. `group` with key `batch` `year` `location`
2. `sort` with `score` `asc`
3. get `top 10` `id, year, batch, location, score` of every group

Comment: where is location in your doc?

Comment: @dev it is my facult, I miss this

Answer (score -1):

Use `aggregation` framework:

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $group: { ... } },
    { $sort: {...} },
    { $limit: 10 }
);
```